# Guava - disk backed large collections

Tags: guava, large-data

Do Guava's collection implementations flow the data to disk beyond a certain size?

I didn't find a simple reference on this, though it sounds like a natural/simple way of supporting large datasets...

We can use other libraries like Map DB of course...or even more comprehensive setups like voldemort...but just wondering why Guava doesn't have it...

Is it that from architecture point of view, if one needs to use such large dataset, he is better off splitting out the data to a separate data store instance instead of putting it in same JVM...?

Comment: Nope; Guava sticks to on-heap collections, just like the ones in java.util.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: That should be an answer, not a comment. =)

Comment: @Sumedh: "but just wondering why Guava doesn't have it"--that's not really a good question for StackOverflow, as it's not a specific _problem_ you want an answer to. The answer, though, is that stuff like that is pretty specialized and not in the domain Guava covers.

Answer (score 1):

Nope; Guava sticks to on-heap collections, just like the ones in java.util.  On-disk collections are more or less out of scope for Guava.